# Fork is not completely synced even after syncing

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I followed this hallowed [page](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) to sync my fork but the fork is still not completely synced. I am working on "develop" branch and the original repo had newly added "develop_backup" branch. But after syncing the fork still the newly added branch also is not reflected; neither are the latest changes.

These are the steps I did after adding remote repo in git settings.

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout develop
git merge upstream/develop
```

But still the Github page of my repo says

```
This branch is 12 commits ahead, 3 commits behind repo:develop
```

And on git merge upstream/develop it says

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Its puzzling as what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must push your changes to the repository.

Assuming "develop" is the branch's name (on the upstream repository)

Use `git push origin develop`

Comment: Great. It helps. But there is one package that exists in my fork but it does not exist in the upstream repo. Should it not be rebased? Also, I do NOT want to push my changes to upstream as it is constantly changing.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand what is your "package"... is it something of your programming language? And I also could not understand why you do not want to PUSH your local changes... it is not that you wanted, in the first place?

Comment: Apologies, that I was vague.I am referring to Java packages here. The repo I have forked from is constantly changing and I want to ensure that my changes do not break it. I will send a Pull Request to merge my changes later. Syncing a fork does not mean that I have to push my changes upstream, correct? It only means that I am pulling changes from the upstream.

Comment: Exactaly, everything that you do in your local repository stays there until you push. But, in order to create a pull request you must push your modification. You said that you forked a repo to your github account, so you can perform a git push (to **your** repository) and after create a pull request(from your repository/branch). Got it? Uh, Java packages are usally not versioned ;)